# Get Next and Previous item from a collection

Tags: magento-1.9, collection

Whats the best way to get the Next and Previous Item from a collection?

Comment: May be it's help you :http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-products/listing-out-previousnext-products-in-magento-inchoo_prevnext-extension/

Answer (score 2):

To Get Next and Previous item from a collection you need to Iterate collection object

For Example

```
foreach($collection as $_collection){
    print_r($_collection->getData())
}
```

If you want to get only first or last item from collection,methods are available for that:

> $collection->getFirstItem() and  $collection->getLastItem()

Answer (score 2):

### Collection itself

As Minesh pointed out indirectly: There is no way using the API of the colletion directly.

The problem is, that magento only implements IteratorAggregate, so the Collection itself doesn't offer what you want.

### The Iterator is an `ArrayIterator`

```
public function getIterator()
{
    $this->load();
    return new ArrayIterator($this->_items);
}
```

[But even with it, you don't have a previous method, but a lot of other methods, have a look in the doc.](http://php.net/manual/de/class.arrayiterator.php)